# Custom search query doesn't seem to be updating

Tags: support, bug, search

I've got the following search result query link:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=java%20-android%20score%3a1%20hasaccepted%3ano%20closed%3ano%20is%3aquestion

However for some reason it doesn't appear to be updating since 1 june, has any substantial change happened to the system that made it happen?

Image:

[image: SO search]

Comment: see [Meta.SE - Search results are old/out of date](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233740/search-results-are-old-out-of-date)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to find the duplicate using the search function.